# Intuitive meaning of orthogonality of linear transformations w.r.t Frobenius (H-S) inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, inner-products

Assume $\langle A,B \rangle = 0$, where $A,B$ are $n \times n$ matrices and $\langle , \rangle$ is the Frobenius inner product. (Also known as the [Hilbert–Schmidt inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator)).

What does it mean intuitively?
In particular, is there some relevant interpretation when we think of $A,B$ as linear transformations?

What about when $\langle A,B \rangle > 0$?

Comment: The Frobenius inner product is the inner product $(\text{Vec}(A),\text{Vec}(B))$, where $\text{Vec}(A)$ is a $n^2$ vector consisting of the components of the matrix. But that's a very roundabout way to think about anything. In my mind, the significance of orthogonality of matrices, is that you can form a Fourier series out of such an orthogonal set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wish I had a better answer for this, and I'm interested to hear what other people say. But one thing to note is that the trace has a physical interpretation: $$\operatorname{Tr}A = \left. \frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\det(I + tA) = \left. \frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\det (e^{tA}).$$

Therefore if you flow along the vector field $F(x)=Ax$, then $\operatorname{Tr}A$ is the amount that this flow distorts volume. (This is paraphrased from a Stack answer somewhere whose link I have lost.)

So to say that $\operatorname{Tr}B^*A=0$ is to say that if you flow by $y'(t) = B^*Ay(t)$ you are not changing volume. (This is the reason why the traceless matrices are the tangent space to $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ at the identity, since $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is defined by its constant determinant.)

Sorry I don't have anything better.

Comment: I think this is a very good answer.